# TextBox in MessageBox in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, messagebox

Is it possible to insert a TextBox for the user to input text on top of a MessageBox in Windows Phone 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - it isn't

But the "Input Prompt" in http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/ might help you. See the overview at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Coding4Fun-Toolkit-for-WP7-Overview-and-Getting-Started

Answer (score 1):

I've used the "Input Prompt" for a situation similar to this and I had no problems. This should work as suggested by Stuart. Also Stuart is right that this is NOT possible at this time.

You might also want to check out Telerik controls, [RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/window.aspx) for WP7 to be specific should address the problem nicely. Only thing is that these are commercial so you'll have to purchase a license.

But if you want to create your own from scratch I watched a video, "[Creating a Custom Popup](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/windows-phone/creating-a-custom-popup-in-windows-phone-7/)", on silverlight.net that can get you started nicely. Basically it gives you the "pop up" and you can add any other controls you need inside of it.

Bear in mind all these solutions can be styled and positioned to "imitate" the look and feel of a messagebox like you wanted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in native MessageBox. You can try [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) library as mentioned before.
An alternative solution is the InputPrompt which can be found in [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radinputprompt-overview.html) library (you will have to pay for this one though).

[image]